# Sumif multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a large sales table with information on sales of a product on a day. So i would like to get the sum of one product sold on a specific day. Because every entry is one customer.  I have so much information, that the formula should search for the correct date and then perform the sum function. I tried array formulas but then my excel complains that it doesn't have enough ressources. Would there be an VBA alternative that i could use?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiViJ.jpg

Comment: Yes. What have you tried? SO is not a free code writing website.

Comment: Try a pivot table

Comment: @Masoud -It's the weekend. I've found that you can either lower your expectations on the quality of questions or go crazy repeating the same *blah-blah-blah* about what this site expects from users posting their problems. TBPH, I've largely given up expecting new users to provide anything close to a quality question. This question is a perfect example of **no sample data except an image that the user expects everyone else to retype** and **no original effort at all**.

Comment: I trust you didn't make the mistake of passing unnecessarily large ranges to your attempt at an array formula? I've often witnessed cases where users, hoping to "cover their bases" with a dataset of potentially-changing length, reference entire columns in an array formula, unaware of the disastrous impact this has on workbook performance.

Comment: Pivot would work. Thanks for the hint. But then i need to find a way to extract the information from the pivot. I don't know how to build a macro that only includes some days into the pivot. Sorry for the low quality question, i will provide more information and data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in G2,

```
=sumifs(index($B:$D, 0, match(G$1, $B$1:$D$1, 0)), $A:$A, $F2)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so i am close to get it. The formula still returns a zero but it should not.                                                                                                         =Sumifs(INDEX(ZP3A!$K:$EM;0;match(L42;ZP3A!$1:$1;0));ZP3A!$C:$C;A2)   The match function and the index function, both work fine. They are returning values. I used array function, but i still get a 0.

Comment: You are indexing K:EM but returning the column position from row 1 (A:XFD). You need to return from K1:EM1. This is **not** an array formula.

Comment: How can i see what array the index funtion returns?

Comment: Well, apparently you have thousands of rows of data but you can check the results by putting a basic SUMIFS that only references one column in an unused cell and comparing the two results.

Comment: Its works, that was my mistake. Ok so for my understanding: the match funtion returns the number of the column with the correct date. But since i put a 0 for row, the index function will now return the complete column that the match function selected. Since it doesn't return just a single value, why it works without array function? It will return a matrix or?

Comment: Almost... the match return the column number **within the range specified**, not the column number on the worksheet unless you are looking within A:XFD. Yes the **0** means the whole column.

Comment: I understand that i get the row number in my range but still i get the whole column and not a specific value. So i should get several values which in my logic means i need to use an array function. But seems i dont understan dsomething here because it work. "If you set Row_num or Column_num to 0 (zero), INDEX returns the array of values for the entire column or row, respectively. To use values returned as an array, enter the INDEX function as an array formula in a horizontal range of cells for a row, and in a vertical range of cells for a column. To enter an array formula, press ...."

Comment: "the index function will now return the complete column that the match function selected. Since it doesn't return just a single value, why it works without array function? It will return a matrix or?" That's because INDEX can handle Arrays and in this case it will pass an Array to SumIfs function. So you won't need any special key stroke i.e. Ctrl+Shift+Enter in this case. Also limit the range reference and don't use whole column otherwise index will return the array of whole column values.